# Find out in which part of the memory a value is being stored?

Tags: c, memory, text, heap-memory, stack-memory

Is there a way to check where a value is being stored in the C memory (heap,stack,text,etc.) using Visual Studio 2015?

For example in this code:

```
char *day(int n) {
static char *name[] = {
"error", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
"thursday", "friday","saturday", "sunday"
};
```

to find out where the array name,name[0],static name, etc. are being stored

Comment: What does Visual Basic have to do with any of this? Are you trying to write a C parser in VB?

Comment: Generally, a program cannot access/modify another programs memory, since this would open up security problems. You could have the c program retrieve the locations and send it to the visual basic program. Also, if you run the program inside a debugger, then its memory can be modified while its running.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13719563/3049655 ?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths My mistake, I wanted to say in Visual Studio.
No I don't. I'm still a C beginner and I'm still learning the basic stuff.
I was just curious about that maybe there is a way to find that out.

Comment: @draganzrilic: The way to find out is just to get familiar with C. `static` variables will exist for the life of the program, so they'll be in whatever the Windows equivalent of the data section is.

Comment: @CoolGuy that's a similiar question,but my question was to find out for every part of the memory,not only heap or stack.
I've imagined that like when you check a file's location, I would find a symbol or etc. that would tell me where a value is being stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check it; you know:

- Automatic variables are on the stack;
- Non-zero initialized (global) variables are in the DATA segment;
- Zero initialized (or not initialized) global variables are in the BSS, which extends the DATA segment;
- Dynamically allocated memory is in the HEAP segment.
- Constant strings may be in the DATA segment or in a separate (write-protected) TEXT segment, but this is up to the compiler.

In your example, `name` will be in the DATA segment and the constant strings in the TEXT segment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.