# Is there a way to check if variable length arrays are created on stack / heap?

Tags: c, arrays, c99

As I understood that the following code generate variable length arrays (via a non standard extension of C++).

```
int main() 
{
    int valone = rand();
    int valtwo = rand();
    int array[valone][valtwo];
    // Printing size
    cout << sizeof(array) << endl;
}
```

Is there any way to check whether its generated on stack or heap? The wikipedia description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) says that `gcc` generates the same in stack, but when I tried above code, most of the times, the array size seems too big to fit into stack, but it never complains.

Note: This code works only with gcc & clang and not with visual studio

Comment: The wikipedia link you point to talks about C99, not C++. `gcc` may or may not treat C99 code and C++ code same.

Comment: Not sure about standard way (as much as "standard" is applicable for "non-standard extension"), but to make a quick test you can compare addresses of `valtwo` and `array[0]`. If array is on the stack, they should be adjacent. If on the heap, they would be quite different. This is not 100% reliable, but will work most of the times.

Comment: It probably won't complain until you access outside temporary storage, but who knows for sure?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13720219/261217

Comment: Note that a stack-overflow situation is not always obvious, especially if you never write to the items at the end of the array (and maybe not even if you do).  So the fact that "it never complains" shouldn't be taken as signifying anything about the implementation of the non-standard extension.

Comment: @RSahu The Wiki link's reference to variable arrays is actually about GNU Fortran! and doesn't support the assertion in any way.

Comment: @EJP, that article talks about many languages, including C99 and Fortran, but not C++. I didn't feel the need to mention any of the languages that are not C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the array size seems too big to fit into stack, but it never complains.

By "never complains", I presume you mean that the program doesn't crash.

You never touch the memory that you allocate and the compiler was smart enough to prove it and didn't allocate anything.

Let us take the address of the variable, and send it to a function that is defined elsewhere:

```
int array[valone][valtwo] = {};
cout << &array << endl;
```

Now, the compiler wasn't quite so sure that the array is never accessed. That's because it can't go into the streaming operator which implemented in another translation unit. Perhaps the operator will dereference the pointer; we must make sure that the array exists.

Segfault crashed this program on my first attempt. The stack was overflown.

---

I suppose this kind of crash test is a way to test if VLA is on the stack.

Mikhail's suggestion in comments to compare adjacency of automatic variables to the VLA is a decent platform dependant idea, but it can only work if you allocate small enough VLA that it doesn't crash the program.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a tricky question and I have tried some thing like

```
#include "iostream"

int Stack_or_heap(void* ptr)
{
 int dummy;
 return ptr > &dummy;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int* i = new int();
   int x, y, z;
   std::cout << Stack_or_heap(&x) << Stack_or_heap(&y) << Stack_or_heap(&z) << Stack_or_heap(i);
}
```

Comment: That's not perfectly reliable, but also clever and the idea might be enough for op. In op's case, you can work with an int directly near the array and check if the addresses of the array and the int are near each other

Answer (score 0):

First I assume you know that any memory chunk allocated in the heap using either malloc or new continues its lifespan throughout the program unless explicitly deallocated. Thus we can conclude, if a variable length array only exists within its scope but not in the lifespan of the program, it is most probably allocated in the stack.

I don't know if there are cases where a chuck of memory is allocated in the heap but behaves as if it is a member of the stack. It is best the see the assembly code for that. Such implementation would probably use dynamic allocation functions/syscalls under the hood.

If it looks like a duck, walks like duck and talks like duck, then it should be safe to assume it is a duck(for the most of the time).

Comment: I think your reasoning in the first paragraph is flawed. If a memory chunk can be allocated implicitly, then that implicitly allocated chunk can also be deallocated implicitly. It is entirely possible that VLA be implemented with malloc.

Comment: It could be and that's the reason why in the second paragraph I state I don't know if there is a case where allocation happens in the heap but behaves as it is a member of the stack. The other way to reason is anything that is allocated in the stack is determined at compile time. That is not true for VLAs in general. As far as I know, anything that is allocated at run time must be allocated in the heap. So we have a dilemma where allocation requirements require the space to be allocated in the heap since it is resolved at run time but behaves as if it is a member of the stack via scope rules.

Comment: The true examination, I think, would require to know the heap address space in the virtual address space.