# Are all members of a Smart Pointer allocated on the Heap?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, unordered-map

Given the following code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Element {

    public:
        Element(const std::string& value) {
            m_value = value;
        }
     
    private:
        std::string m_value;

};

class Container {

    public:
        Container(const std::string& value) {
            m_elements.emplace(std::make_pair("New Key",Element(value)));
        }

    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, Element> m_elements;

};

int main() {

    std::string str {"New Value"};
    auto container = std::make_shared<Container>(str);

    return 0;

}
```

Will all members of the `Container` `shared_ptr` instance be stored on Heap, including all instances of the `Element` class inside the `m_elements` `unordered_map`? My question comes down to: Are all members of a `shared_ptr` stored on the Heap?

Comment: Seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or you just want to know where are they allocated?

Comment: Except `str` might be allocated on heap due to small string optimization. Others shall be allocaed on heap.

Comment: A side note, in general, constructors containing arguments like `std::string` may use move semantic for better performance. Eg: `Element(std::string value): m_value(std::move(value))`.

Comment: The `shared_ptr` is stored on the stack just like an `int`. The thing that the `shared_ptr` points to, however, is stored on the heap, in particular, when it is generated with `make_shared`.

Comment: @LouisGo I just wanted to know where they are allocated, thanks

Comment: You may start from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13719563/4123703) to check them by inspecting address of variable.  But keep in mind that it's implementation details and not portable.

Comment: @jcjuarez The elements of your `unordered_map` will be allocated on the heap, **irrespective** of whether it is contained in a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @jcjuarez Using a shared_ptr<T> means that the direct members of the T will be allocated on the heap. In your case that means `m_elements`. But it has no effect at all on the indirect members of T. In your case that means the elements contained inside `m_elements`. **But** those elements are allocated on the heap anyway, because that's how `unordered_map` works.

Comment: @jcjuarez I'm not sure that the C++ standard actually says that all elements contained in an `unordered_map` must be allocated on the heap. So the above comment should be understood with the caveat - as `unordered_map` is typically implemented

Comment: @john Yeah - the C++ Standard doesn't have any concept of "heap" or "stack". Neither does the language *require* that a target platform has both of those.

Comment: *Are all members of a Smart Pointer allocated on the Heap?*  No.  And in typical usage, it'd be really odd if any of the members of a Smart Pointer are allocated on the Heap.

Comment: @john so following what you said taking the code example, if both the `Container` and `Element` classes now each had a new `int m_container` and `int m_element` respectively, that means that by creating a `shared_ptr<Container>` then `int m_container` would be stored on the Heap as it is a direct member of `shared_ptr<Container>` and `int m_element` would be stored on the stack as it is not a direct member?

Comment: If I want to make sure that a T class instance is always stored on the Heap should I always try to define them as smart pointers then?

Comment: @jcjuarez In the code you have written above both `m_container` and `m_element` will be on the heap. `m_container` because it's part of a shared_ptr and `m_element` because it's part of an unordered_map.

Comment: @jcjuarez Always allocating an instance as the target of a shared_ptr will ensure that it is allocated on the heap. But the question has to be asked, why do you care? I can't help feeling that there is some misunderstanding behind your questions.

Comment: @john okay, and now if we had a new `Element m_element_instance` member in the `Container` class, then would the `int m_element` of that new particular `m_element_instance` be also stored on the heap as `m_element_instance` was a direct member of the Smart Pointer?

Comment: @john I ask this because I want to understand correctly how allocation works, as I would’t want to make the mistake of allocating heavy class instances on the stack

Comment: @jcjuarez Generally speaking allocating objects on the stack is more efficient than allocating them on the heap.

Comment: @jcjuarez Yes, m_element is a direct member of Element, m_element_instance is a direct member of Container. Container is on the heap therefore m_element is too.

Answer (score 3):

> Are all members of a Smart Pointer allocated on the Heap?

If an object has dynamic storage duration, then by definition, that object is not a member object. All data members are stored within the memory of the enclosing object.

A smart pointer is a stateful object, and in practice, it needs at least one subject to represent that state. It could be a direct data member, or a data member of a base class.

`std::make_shared<Container>` crates an instance of `Container` with dynamic storage duration, and returns a shared pointer that owns the instance.

Comment: Member subobjects can definitely have dynamic storage duration—it has to be the same as the complete object.